# Uploading UIImage to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uiimage, pfimageview

I have been having a lot of trouble trying to get my photo picker to pick an image, cast it as a Pffile, then upload it to Parse.

I have currently taped together what I have so I could see it being something simple that I can't see.

The error I get is:

reason: 'PFObject values may not have class: UIImage'

Any Ideas?

```
@IBAction func selectUser(sender: AnyObject) {
    let photoPicker = UIImagePickerController()
    photoPicker.delegate = self
    photoPicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary

    self.presentViewController(photoPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.05)
    let imageFile = PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:imageData!)




    picSlot.file = imageFile
    let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()
    if currentUser != nil {
        PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(image, forKey: "userPic")
    }

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the following:

```
if currentUser != nil {
    PFUser.currentUser()?.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "userPic")
}
```

You can't explicitly set the UIImage as a member of the PFObject, but you can set a PFFile as a PFObject's attribute.